# standar error of non-linear regression

Tags: least-squares, standard-error, curve-fitting, nonlinear, statsmodels

I'm trying to compute the standar error of a non-linear regression fit, I find the answer in this post

[Non-linear regression confidence interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72047/when-fitting-a-curve-how-do-i-calculate-the-95-confidence-interval-for-my-fitt)

But i did't find that formula in any other place,and I just can't do my homework using a formula without any source or proof. Could you please help me?

Comment: Standard error of what quantity?

Comment: Have you tried googling for "non-linear least squares" analysis?  There are many stats references on line.  http://math.gmu.edu/~igriva/book/Appendix%20D.pdf page 754.